# push json get request items into an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to push json objects into an array with angular. I'm getting an error 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'. Is there another way to do this with angular?

```
$.each(data.Document.Placemark, function(index, item) {
   var locations = [];
  $scope.locations.push(item.name + ", " + item.Point.coordinates);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `locations` to be a property of `$scope` then you have to make it a property of `$scope` instead of a local variable.

```
$scope.locations = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

.push method is only used for arrays. You should define an array first before using .push
You should do this:

```
$.each(data.Document.Placemark, function(index, item) {
   $scope.locations = [];
   $scope.locations.push(item.name + ", " + item.Point.coordinates);
});
```